# Use GroupBy to Partition Set by Overlapping Ranges

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, partitioning

Consider a class `Rectangle` that defines a region by the corners:

```
public class Rectangle {
    public int X1 { get; set; }
    public int Y1 { get; set; }
    public int X2 { get; set; }
    public int Y2 { get; set; }
}
```

It can be said that two `Rectangle` objects `Overlap` if they have any regions in common.  Here's a simple method that implements the `Overlap` logic:

```
public bool Overlaps(Rectangle other) {
    return (this.X1 < other.X2 && this.X2 > other.X1 &&
        this.Y1 < other.Y2 && this.Y2 > other.Y1);
}
```

Now I want to partition a set of `Rectangle` objects into groups of overlapping rectangles.  The catch is that some rectangles in the group may not necessarily overlap other rectangles in the same group, as long as they share other overlapping rectangles.  The result is always well-defined, but there is no direct mapping from the rectangles to the final overlapping groups.

It seems intuitively that it should be possible to use `GroupBy` to build groups of overlapping rectangles.  However, there is no "key" that defines whether rectangles belong to the same group; what matters is if they overlap.  Can this problem be solved using `GroupBy`, even if it means grouping recursively until all the proper groups are combined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `GroupBy` expects a property that can be determined by looking at one instance, and one instance only.

However, there is a relatively straightforward solution: you can use a [*Disjoint-Set Data Structure*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) (which is a little more than a glorified linked list), and its associated `union` algorithm. The whole algorithm can be coded up in a few dozen lines, and is relatively simple to understand and debug.

Give your rectangles sequential numbers, and run your intersection algorithm on each pair of rectangles. When you detect an overlap, perform set union on the corresponding disjoint set structures. When you are done, each member will point to the "root" number for its set. You can use these root numbers to group by the list in LINQ.

Answer (score 3):

In case somebody looks for actual implementation. It's not for rectangles but for time ranges tho.
DisjointSet implementation is taken from 
http://www.mathblog.dk/disjoint-set-data-structure/

```
public class Range {
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime Stop { get; set; }
    public int Parent { get; set; }

    public Range(DateTime start, DateTime stop)
    {
        Start = start;
        Stop = stop;
    }
}

void Main()
{
    List<Range> ranges = new List<Range>();
    ranges.Add(new Range(new DateTime(2019, 10, 1), new DateTime(2019, 10, 2)));
    ranges.Add(new Range(new DateTime(2019, 10, 2), new DateTime(2019, 10, 3)));
    ranges.Add(new Range(new DateTime(2019, 10, 1), new DateTime(2019, 10, 3)));
    ranges.Add(new Range(new DateTime(2019, 10, 4), new DateTime(2019, 10, 5)));
    ranges.Add(new Range(new DateTime(2019, 10, 6), new DateTime(2019, 10, 8)));
    ranges.Add(new Range(new DateTime(2019, 10, 5), new DateTime(2019, 10, 7)));
    ranges.Add(new Range(new DateTime(2019, 10, 9), new DateTime(2019, 10, 9)));


    var set = new DisjointSet(ranges.Count());
    var IsOverlaping = new Func<Range, Range, bool>((a, b) => a.Start < b.Stop && b.Start < a.Stop  );

    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.Count; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < ranges.Count; j++)
        {
            if (IsOverlaping(ranges[i], ranges[j]))
            {
                set.Union(i,j);
            }
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < set.Count; i++)
    {
        ranges[i].Parent = set.Parent[i];
    }
    ranges.GroupBy(x=> x.Parent);

}

/// <summary>
/// A Union-Find/Disjoint-Set data structure.
/// </summary>
public class DisjointSet {

    /// <summary>
    /// The number of elements in the universe.
    /// </summary>
    public int Count { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The parent of each element in the universe.
    /// </summary>
    public int[] Parent;

    /// <summary>
    /// The rank of each element in the universe.
    /// </summary>
    private int[] Rank;

    /// <summary>
    /// The size of each set.
    /// </summary>
    private int[] SizeOfSet;

    /// <summary>
    /// The number of disjoint sets.
    /// </summary>
    public int SetCount { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new Disjoint-Set data structure, with the specified amount of elements in the universe.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name='count'>
    /// The number of elements in the universe.
    /// </param>
    public DisjointSet(int count) {
        this.Count = count;
        this.SetCount = count;
        this.Parent = new int[this.Count];
        this.Rank = new int[this.Count];
        this.SizeOfSet = new int[this.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < this.Count; i++) {
            this.Parent[i] = i;
            this.Rank[i] = 0;
            this.SizeOfSet[i] = 1;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find the parent of the specified element.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name='i'>
    /// The specified element.
    /// </param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// All elements with the same parent are in the same set.
    /// </remarks>
    public int Find(int i) {
        if (this.Parent[i] == i) {
            return i;
        } else {
            // Recursively find the real parent of i, and then cache it for later lookups.
            this.Parent[i] = this.Find(this.Parent[i]);
            return this.Parent[i];
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unite the sets that the specified elements belong to.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name='i'>
    /// The first element.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name='j'>
    /// The second element.
    /// </param>
    public void Union(int i, int j)
    {

        // Find the representatives (or the root nodes) for the set that includes i
        int irep = this.Find(i),
            // And do the same for the set that includes j
            jrep = this.Find(j),
            // Get the rank of i's tree
            irank = this.Rank[irep],
            // Get the rank of j's tree
            jrank = this.Rank[jrep];

        // Elements are in the same set, no need to unite anything.
        if (irep == jrep)
            return;

        this.SetCount--;

        // If i's rank is less than j's rank
        if (irank < jrank)
        {

            // Then move i under j
            this.Parent[irep] = jrep;
            this.SizeOfSet[jrep] += this.SizeOfSet[irep];

        } // Else if j's rank is less than i's rank
        else if (jrank < irank)
        {

            // Then move j under i
            this.Parent[jrep] = irep;
            this.SizeOfSet[irep] += this.SizeOfSet[jrep];

        } // Else if their ranks are the same
        else
        {

            // Then move i under j (doesn't matter which one goes where)
            this.Parent[irep] = jrep;
            this.SizeOfSet[jrep] += this.SizeOfSet[irep];

            // And increment the the result tree's rank by 1
            this.Rank[jrep]++;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the element count of the set that the specified elements belong to.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name='i'>
    /// The element.
    /// </param>
    public int SetSize(int i)
    {
        return this.SizeOfSet[this.Find(i)];
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]